# CSS align buttons

Tags: html, css

I have 3 buttons, 1 of them has an image. The issue is that the last one doesn´t render align with the other othe buttons.

```css
.matrix-size {
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

<button class="matrix-size">$$ { \left( 2 \times 4 \right) } $$</button>
<button class="matrix-size">$$ { \left( 5 \times 5 \right) } $$</button>
<button class="matrix-size"><img src="https://es.symbolab.com/public/img/pad_matrixnxn.png
"></button>
```

What should I do to make them aligned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the vertical align to something other than the default of baseline. Try top:

```css
.matrix-size {
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

<button class="matrix-size">$$ { \left( 2 \times 4 \right) } $$</button>
<button class="matrix-size">$$ { \left( 5 \times 5 \right) } $$</button>
<button class="matrix-size"><img src="https://es.symbolab.com/public/img/pad_matrixnxn.png
"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.matrix-size {
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: top;
    

}
```

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

<button class="matrix-size">$$ { \left( 2 \times 4 \right) } $$</button>
<button class="matrix-size">$$ { \left( 5 \times 5 \right) } $$</button>
<button class="matrix-size"><img src="https://es.symbolab.com/public/img/pad_matrixnxn.png
"></button>
```

Comment: Already answered. And please comment as to why this is

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.